# Execute two process in parallel in Python

Tags: python, shell, parallel-processing

I am trying to execute two commands in parallel for 10 seconds using the following piece of code, but the whole process takes more than 10 seconds as you can see in the output. Would you please help me to better understand the reason and the best solution for this question.

```
stime = datetime.datetime.now()
print stime
commands = ("sudo /usr/local/bin/snort -v -u snort -g snort -c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort.conf -i eth0 &", "sudo gedit test")
for p in commands:
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(p), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    class Alarm(Exception):
        pass
    def alarm_handler(signum, frame):
        raise Alarm
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
    signal.alarm(10) #in seconds
    try:
        stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()
        signal.alarm(0) #reset the alarm
    except Alarm:
        print 'Ooops, taking too long!!!!'
etime = datetime.datetime.now() 
print etime
```

And the output:

```
2013-01-08 03:30:00.836412
Ooops, taking too long!!!!
2013-01-08 03:30:16.548519
```

Comment: What are these processes aiming to do?

Comment: I like to execute two programs, Snort as a detection engine and Wireshark as a traffic capture tool. In my code I just put 'gedit test' instead of Wireshark.
These two packages are analyzing the traffic packets received in a specified period of time (10 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

I feel like a `threading.Timer` might be more appropriate:

```
from threading import Timer
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import shlex
import datetime
import sys

jobs = ['sleep 100','sleep 200']

timers = []
processes = []
print datetime.datetime.now()
for job in jobs:
    p = Popen(shlex.split(job),stdout = PIPE)
    t = Timer(10,lambda p=p: p.terminate())
    t.start()
    timers.append(t)
    processes.append(p)

for t in timers:
    t.join()

stdout,stderr = processes[0].communicate()    
stdout,stderr = processes[1].communicate()
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: I guess this solution is working. I need to test my jobs which are two network traffic analyzers and then see if they are capturing traffic in parallel. BTW, are these two jobs running in the background?

Comment: @samaneh -- What do you mean background?  They're not blocking your main thread of execution if that's what you're wondering...

Comment: I was thinking of if I can see the programs in the Terminal while they are running. I just checked your code and it seems that everything is working fine. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What I have noticed after running the code is that the process is not producing the output it should. Do we need p.communicate() somewhere in our code?

Comment: Yeah, you can `p.communicate()` after you `join` the threads...I've updated with a solution that I think should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import shlex
import time

commands = ("echo -n HI-FIRST ", "echo -n HI-SECOND ")
def parallel():
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()
    print stdoutdata + "\t" + time.ctime()
for cmd in commands:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=parallel)
    p.start()
```

**Output:**

```
$ python stack.py 
HI-FIRST    Fri Jan 11 08:47:18 2013
HI-SECOND   Fri Jan 11 08:47:18 2013
```

Comment: Is it possible to run two commands for a specified period of time like 10 seconds in parallel?